# Python Show webpage on connect to server

Tags: javascript, python, sendfile

I built a server using JavaScript that displayed a webpage when you connected to it. The server sent the htm file upon connection using

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('index.htm');
});
```

Is there a similar function in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer

PORT = 8000

Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler

httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)

print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

see https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html